# CMake download issue when building OpenCV behind proxy

Tags: opencv, cmake

I'm trying to install OpenCV 3.1.0 (with contrib) on CentOS 7 behind a proxy. I get download errors for the 3rd party libraries. I've tried setting the HTTP_PROXY (also http_proxy, https_proxy, ftp_proxy and their uppercase versions) environment variable but it doesn't make a difference. Here's the command I use:

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE \
    -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local \
    -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=~/opencv_contrib/modules \
    -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=OFF \
    -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON \
    -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON \
    -D BUILD_OPENCV_PYTHON2=ON ..
```

And here's the error I get:

```
-- Detected version of GNU GCC: 48 (408)
-- Found ZLIB: /lib64/libz.so (found suitable version "1.2.7", minimum required is "1.2.3") 
-- Found ZLIB: /lib64/libz.so (found version "1.2.7") 
-- Found OpenEXR: /lib64/libIlmImf.so
-- checking for module 'gtk+-3.0'
--   package 'gtk+-3.0' not found
-- checking for module 'gstreamer-base-1.0'
--   package 'gstreamer-base-1.0' not found
-- checking for module 'gstreamer-video-1.0'
--   package 'gstreamer-video-1.0' not found
-- checking for module 'gstreamer-app-1.0'
--   package 'gstreamer-app-1.0' not found
-- checking for module 'gstreamer-riff-1.0'
--   package 'gstreamer-riff-1.0' not found
-- checking for module 'gstreamer-pbutils-1.0'
--   package 'gstreamer-pbutils-1.0' not found
-- Looking for linux/videodev.h
-- Looking for linux/videodev.h - not found
-- Looking for linux/videodev2.h
-- Looking for linux/videodev2.h - found
-- Looking for sys/videoio.h
-- Looking for sys/videoio.h - not found
-- checking for module 'libavcodec'
--   package 'libavcodec' not found
-- checking for module 'libavformat'
--   package 'libavformat' not found
-- checking for module 'libavutil'
--   package 'libavutil' not found
-- checking for module 'libswscale'
--   package 'libswscale' not found
-- checking for module 'libavresample'
--   package 'libavresample' not found
-- Looking for libavformat/avformat.h
-- Looking for libavformat/avformat.h - not found
-- Looking for ffmpeg/avformat.h
-- Looking for ffmpeg/avformat.h - not found
-- checking for module 'libgphoto2'
--   package 'libgphoto2' not found
CMake Warning at 3rdparty/ippicv/downloader.cmake:56 (message):
  ICV: Local copy of ICV package has invalid MD5 hash:
  d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e (expected:
  808b791a6eac9ed78d32a7666804320e)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  3rdparty/ippicv/downloader.cmake:110 (_icv_downloader)
  cmake/OpenCVFindIPP.cmake:237 (include)
  cmake/OpenCVFindLibsPerf.cmake:12 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:537 (include)


-- ICV: Downloading ippicv_linux_20151201.tgz...
CMake Error at 3rdparty/ippicv/downloader.cmake:73 (file):
  file DOWNLOAD HASH mismatch

    for file: [/home/hal/opencv/3rdparty/ippicv/downloads/linux-808b791a6eac9ed78d32a7666804320e/ippicv_linux_20151201.tgz]
      expected hash: [808b791a6eac9ed78d32a7666804320e]
        actual hash: [d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e]

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  3rdparty/ippicv/downloader.cmake:110 (_icv_downloader)
  cmake/OpenCVFindIPP.cmake:237 (include)
  cmake/OpenCVFindLibsPerf.cmake:12 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:537 (include)


CMake Error at 3rdparty/ippicv/downloader.cmake:77 (message):
  ICV: Failed to download ICV package: ippicv_linux_20151201.tgz.
  Status=7;"Couldn't connect to server"
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  3rdparty/ippicv/downloader.cmake:110 (_icv_downloader)
  cmake/OpenCVFindIPP.cmake:237 (include)
  cmake/OpenCVFindLibsPerf.cmake:12 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:537 (include)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

Comment: But cmake fails at the end? Because I believe those libraries that are marked as **not found** are not supposed to be downloaded during opencv compilation.

Comment: For instance, from the opencv installation [tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_install/linux_install.html), as a prerequisite of opencv you have to install **libavcodec-dev, libavformat-dev**, which are not being found by you cmake.

Comment: Cmake fails because those libraries aren't found, it tries to download them, but fails to do so, so the resulting files are 0kb, so their hash doesn't match the hash it expects, so the requirements are not met, so it fails to cmake.

Comment: How do you know that _it tries to download them_? The cmake log shows that? Why don't you try to install them manually through your package manager?

Comment: Do you not see the cmake log I posted? It says "-- ICV: Downloading ippicv_linux_20151201.tgz..."

Comment: No, my apologies, I did not notice the scroll. You can manually download that package. [Source](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/5973)